# Wouldn't it be more efficient to let the kidneys flow into the intestines?

Tags: human-biology

So I was thinking about how much fluids we lose when we pee. Then I realised that it would be much more efficient to remove the bladder and let it flow into the intestines so that the fluids can be reabsorbed.

What probles would arise from letting pee flow into the intestines? Also, where would be the optimal place to let the pee arrive? In the small intestine or closer to the anus?

Comment: You want continuous diarrhoea, and kidney infections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then I realised that it would be much more efficient to remove the bladder and let it flow into the intestines so that the fluids can be reabsorbed.

No. This would be very, very bad.

First, the kidney is very good at water conservation when necessary. If you're peeing up a storm, then you're drinking up a storm.

It is much more efficient to flush out waste products through the kidneys, and simply drink when thirsty. So you pee a lot. That's ok. It all ends up in the water cycle.

But emptying the ureters in any part of the digestive tract would mean terrible diarrhea, the kind that your bottom would burn like crazy every time you went (and you would hardly be able to control it, meaning large laundry bills) unless you used a protective ointment barrier between your skin and your diarrhea. To keep that skin from breaking down (yes, breaking down), you would need to bathe your bottom after every bowel movement. And it just would not be as good for fluid and electrolyte balance.

Also, the urinary tract is *relatively* sterile, protecting the kidneys from infection. The GI tract is anything but. The result would likely be so many ascending bacterial infections that your poor kidneys would be scarred and useless at a young age.

Nope, nope, nope.

Answer (score -3):

Urine is acidic. It would irritate the bowels. It would also react with and spoil chemicals in the intestines that the body wants to recover like thyroxine. In general, the intestinal pathway is for fat-soluble materials and the urinary pathway is for water-soluble waste.

The body can absorb water from urine. For example, camels have very thick urine. Thicker urine is more acidic, so the camel's bladder has to be tougher.